# multivariate polynomial over a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $f=1+x^2+xy+x^2y$, $p=1+x^2+y^2+xy^2$ and $q=1+x^2+y+xy$, $p,q\in\mathbb F_2[x,y]$.

I've read: because the gcd of $p$ and $q$ is $d=1+x$ and $d|f$ there are $r,s\in\mathbb F_2[x,y]$ s.t. $f=rp+sq$ (I know that this is true in a PID, which $\mathbb F_2[x,y]$ isn't). (It is also said that the gcd is obtained by euclidean algorithm. What is ment by that? I only know the EA for euclidean domains.)

This doesn't seem correct? What would be the justification for that? I mean the gcd of $x$ and $y$ is $1$, but $xr+ys\ne 1$ for any $r,s$.

Comment: Where did you read that?

Comment: The claim is false (as my answer shows). There may be a typo somewhere. If you give more context then perhaps we can figure out what was intended.

Comment: It would work like this in the polynomial ring $\Bbb{F}_2(y)[x]$ which is a Euclidean domain by virtue of $\Bbb{F}_2(y)$ being a field. It doesn't work this in $\Bbb{F}_2[x,y]$. See Bill Dubuque's answer for a nice argument. Anyway, if you allow $r,s\in\Bbb{F}_2(y)[x]$ then there shouldn't be any problems (probably a coefficient of either $r$ or $s$ will have a denominator vanishing at $y=1$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is false. Evaluating $\,f = rp+sr $ at $x=0,y=1$ yields $\,1 = r\cdot 0 + s\cdot 0 = 0,\,$ contradiction.